# How to show each object from json out put individually in swift

Tags: json, swift

Currently I able to show full out out from GET method which return json data.

but I am unable to show individual object . i.e values of description or engine . but I can print the whole json data.
my code

```
 let url = URL(string: "https://mylink/last")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Session": "b14549"
        ]


        let session =  URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let response = response {
                print (response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                print (data)
                do {
                    let jsonresult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

// This works
                    print (jsonresult)

                    // Bellow does not work , Give Error Value of type 'any' has no subscripts
                    print (jsonresult["device_id"])
                    print (jsonresult["engine"])



                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }


            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

I looked at other solution , tried bellow not working not sure if its related to the data type I am getting. I have posted the out put of jsonresult bellow.

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
```

out put of Json result : -

```
(
        {

        "device_id" = "3aff273f-7f5f-49ef-81a6-50e2fcc2f69f”;
            engine = 0;

        "last_timestamp" = "2019-10-25 17:33:45";


    },
        {

        "device_id" = "44b0ab5f-5289-4c56-b864-ce4899c2fcb8”;
        engine = 0;

        "last_timestamp" = "2019-10-25 17:33:40";

    },
        {

        "device_id" = "c5639e8b-7f56-4021-9925-828ed735f527";

        engine = 0;


    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The result is clearly an array, please note the `()` in the output.
2. You have to cast the result to the expected type

   ```
   if let jsonresult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String:Any]] {
      for item in jsonresult {
         print(item["device_id"])
         print(item["engine"])
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Just for my understanding ```.  print (type(of: jsonresult))``` , this gives me  ``` . Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> ```. that's why we put jsonresult into Array, then call each object, right ?

Comment: Yes `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` and `[[String:Any]]` are synonyms. We don't *put jsonresult into Array*, `jsonresult` **is** Array, we downcast unspecified `Any` to the proper type.